# Grafico de Google Charts con registros de un Datatable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datatables

Tengo un problema, necesito implementar un gráfico de barras (Google Charts) a un Datatable, tengo cargado registros dinámicamente al Datatable, el Grafico de barra que tengo implementado a través del console.log me indica que la función implementada esta respondiendo ok pero al final cuando tiene que mostrar los datos finales no los muestra no imprime en la pagina, creo que no se esta mostrando el Grafico después de la inicialización de Datatables. Lamentablemente no consigo avanzar más porque desconozco otras salidas para corregir este problema.

```
//charts2.js
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => {
    console.log(getDataTable());
    updateBarChart();
  });


// Función para crear o actualizar el gráfico de barras
function updateBarChart() {
    console.log("Updating bar chart...");
    //Obtener el DataTable creado en script.js
    let dataTable = getDataTable();  //Este codigo REEMPLAZO a let dataTable = window.dataTable; 
    console.log("DataTable:", dataTable);
    if (!dataTable) {
       console.error('DataTable is not available. Make sure the DataTable is loaded in script.js before chart2.js.');
        return;
    }

    // Obtener los datos del DataTable y organizarlos en arreglos para el gráfico
    let dataByAlmacen = {}; // Objeto para almacenar los datos por almacén

    // Recorrer las filas del DataTable (omitimos la primera fila que contiene los encabezados)
    let tableRows = dataTable.rows().data();
    tableRows.each(function (data) {
        let almacen = data[0]; // Columna de los almacenes
        let dato1 = parseFloat(data[7]); // Columna del dato1 (Ord)
        let dato2 = parseFloat(data[8]); // Columna del dato2 (Asig)
        let dato3 = parseFloat(data[9]); // Columna del dato3 (Pick)

        // Verificar si el almacén ya existe en el objeto, si no, lo agregamos con valores iniciales
        if (!dataByAlmacen[almacen]) {
            dataByAlmacen[almacen] = {
                dato1: 0,
                dato2: 0,
                dato3: 0
            };
        }

        // Acumulamos los datos en el objeto para el almacén correspondiente
        dataByAlmacen[almacen].dato1 += dato1;
        dataByAlmacen[almacen].dato2 += dato2;
        dataByAlmacen[almacen].dato3 += dato3;
    });

    // Crear el arreglo de datos para el gráfico
    var dataArray = [['Almacén', 'Ord', 'Asig', 'Pick']];
    for (var almacen in dataByAlmacen) {
        dataArray.push([
            almacen,
            dataByAlmacen[almacen].dato1,
            dataByAlmacen[almacen].dato2,
            dataByAlmacen[almacen].dato3
        ]);
    }

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

    var options = {
        title: 'Tasa de Servicio: Asignacion de Articulos por Centro de Distribucion',
        titleTextStyle: { fontSize: 18 }, // Tamaño del título del gráfico
        vAxis: { title: 'Valores' },
        hAxis: { title: 'Almacén' },
        legend: { position: 'top' },
        bar: { groupWidth: '95%' } // Ajustar el ancho de las barras, un valor menor a 1 las hace más anchas
    };
    console.log("Data Array:", dataArray);
    console.log("Options:", options);
    // Crear o actualizar el gráfico de barras
    var barChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    barChart.draw(data, options);
    console.log("Bar Chart Drawn on the webpage");
}

//script.js (carga dinamica del Datatable)
let data;
// Esta función inicializa el DataTable con las opciones especificadas en 'dataTableOptions'.
// Selecciona el elemento con el id "example" y crea el DataTable con las opciones en 'dataTableOptions'.
const initDataTable = () => {
  console.log("Initializing DataTable...");
  dataTable = $('#example').DataTable(dataTableOptions); 
  console.log("DataTable Initialized");
  
  updateBarChart();
  
  console.log("Bar Chart Updated");
};
const loadJsonDataToDataTable = (jsonData) => {
  if (!jsonData || jsonData.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  // Limpiar el DataTable antes de cargar nuevos datos.
  dataTable.clear().draw();
  // Agregar los registros al DataTable iterando por cada objeto en jsonData.
  jsonData.forEach((data) => {
    // Verificar si la columna Almacén está vacía.
   if (data[9] !== "") {
    // Convertir el objeto de datos a un array con las columnas seleccionadas en el orden deseado.
    const rowData = [
            data.Almc,
            data.Articulo,
            data.Descripcion,
            data.Stock,
            data.InvAsigTotal,
            data.Reserva,
            data.Transito,
            data.CntOrd,
            data.CntAsig,
            data.CntPick,
            data.FaltPick
    ]
    //console.log(rowData);
    // Convertir el array a formato JSON con comillas dobles y luego analizarlo para asegurar el formato JSON válido.
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(rowData);
    const jsonDataParsed = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  
    // Agregar el objeto jsonDataParsed directamente como una nueva fila al DataTable.
    dataTable.row.add(jsonDataParsed).draw();
  }
  });
};

document.getElementById("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", function (event) {
  // Obtener el archivo seleccionado del input file.
  const selectedFile = event.target.files[0];

  // Verificar si se seleccionó un archivo.
  if (selectedFile) {
    // Crear un nuevo objeto FileReader.
    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    // Definir la función de callback para cuando el archivo se haya leído completamente.
    fileReader.onload = function (event) {
      // Obtener los datos del archivo leído como una cadena binaria.
      var data = event.target.result;
      
      // Leer el archivo como un libro de Excel usando la biblioteca XLSX.
      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "binary" });

      var jsonData = [];

      // Iterar a través de cada hoja del libro de Excel.
      workbook.SheetNames.forEach(sheet => {
        // Convertir la hoja actual a un array de objetos JSON y agregarlo a jsonData usando el operador spread (...)
        var rowObject = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheet]);
        jsonData.push(...rowObject);
      });
      //console.log(jsonData);
      // Llamar a la función para cargar los datos al DataTable con el JSON obtenido del archivo Excel.
      loadJsonDataToDataTable(jsonData);
    };

    // Leer el archivo seleccionado como una cadena binaria para poder procesarlo con la biblioteca XLSX.
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
  }
});

// Retorna DataTable para el grafico
function getDataTable() {
  return dataTable;
}
 
// Ejecutar la función initDataTable al cargar la página para inicializar el DataTable.
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  //console.log("Window Loaded");
  initDataTable();
  updateBarChart()
  
});
```